# Spark plug wire order for new set

Tags: chevrolet

Done did me a rookie mistake, pulled all the spark plug wires out, ran to Napa n got new set, came back and was scratching my head.

Working on a 98 chevy s10 4.3l v6.
Anyone have pictures of the exact wire placements for this vehicle?

Comment: There will be no diagram for each wire placement, should be easy to sort out as they are different lengths and can only go in one place or two.

Answer (score 1):

The distributor cap will have cylinder numbers on it.

Cylinders #1, #3, and #5 are on the left side (drivers).
Cylinders #2, #4, and #6 are on the right side.
Cylinders #1 and #2 will be in the front of the engine.
Cylinders #5 and #6 are in the rear of the engine.

Be careful, as #3 and #1 will not be where you expect - #1 will be in between #3 and #5 on the distributor.

Answer (score 0):

This diagram should do you (a quick google search so do check):

[image: the 4.3 engine]

The source, which also shows the 2.8L if needed:

[Link to source](https://www.2carpros.com/questions/chevrolet-s-10-1993-chevy-s-10--28)

It is also a good idea to check that the distributor is correctly timed... Having had problems due to a distributor being timed 1 plug out so each position was rotated by one...

Comment: I know the firing order, im trying to figure out witch wires i need to place in certain areas cause they are different sizes and some boots are shaped straight and 90° angles.

Comment: The exact routing between distributor and plug depends on the brackets & supports available on the engine. You could search on google to see if someone has photos they took before changing their leads... If not, then you need to place the leads with positioning that seems sensible. The image I provided shows which post on the distributor connects to which cylinder, which is what I thought you asked for in your question.